# Development of logical thinking/problem solving/learning capacity associated with math/physics

Tags: learning

I was wondering how logical thinking/problem solving ability/learning capacity evolves and develops in individuals that study math/physics.(that need a lot of logical thinking)

So my question is basically : **Does studying math/physics helps you solving problems or learning other things that are not directly linked with any of this subjects ?** (problems from other subjects like biology or problems concerning our daily life)

I don't know if there's any research in that field (concerning some kind of facility of learning/solving other things when you've studied subjects that need a lot of logical thinking).

Comment: A few similar questions: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/207/7001, https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/15779/7001, https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/1415/7001.

Comment: another related question is the following : [Chess to enhance human cognitive abilities?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/15764/chess-to-enhance-human-cognitive-abilities)